# How can I suppress android's default inputType keypad?

Tags: android, onclick, android-edittext

Is there any way to suppress the default inputType keypad of android's EditText view. I have an event handler attached to android:onClick but it only gets fired after the keypad displays. If it's possible I would like to mute the keypad and let my event handler do all the work. Many thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

After searching and trying stuff for about an hour, I finally arrived at a solution that suits my need. I discovered that setting android:focusable="false" while having android:onClick="myEventHandler" prevents the keypad from displaying yet my event handler gets fired.  I hope someone else finds this useful.  Thanks for your help.